# Что в моём складе является сущностью розничной продажи для JSON API?

Tags: moysklad-json-api

Что в моём складе является сущностью розничной продажи для JSON API?

Answer (score 0):

`retaildemand`. Причем в api есть полный инструментарий для работы с розничными продажами. Подробнее [тут](https://online.moysklad.ru/api/remap/1.1/doc/index.html#%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82-%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B0-%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B8-get)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Возможно, не так понял вопрос?